# Cannot import correctly uniswap's permit2

Tags: solidity, import, allowance

Hello i am trying to import the permit2 following the official uniswap's guide but i cannot manage to import it correctly since it lacks of the structs and more things even if i don't get any error when importing it.

```
import {IAllowanceTransfer} from "@uniswap/Permit2/src/interfaces/IAllowanceTransfer.sol";
```

this is what i'm trying to do, could someone help me out?

Comment: What's the error? Can you share your code? Are you using the correct version of the uniswap package?

Comment: @Ismael hi, i imported it directly from github and all seems to work!

Comment: Please, add your solution as answer so it can help others!